# Having problems with putting a price on the input from a JOptionPane drop list

Tags: java, netbeans, joptionpane

Hey I have been working on this assignment, and I have hit a wall, not really sure where to go from here now but I need to put a price to match each weight category in each method. The price will then need to be used to generate the vat as well as the overall total.

```
   public class Delivery_Details 
       {
        private static String Timestamp;
        private static String tChoice;
        private static String wChoice;
        private static String cChoice;
        private static int price;
        private static int vat;
        public static int total;


       public static void main(String[] args) {

        townChoices();
        weightChoices();
        courierChoices();
        printDetails();

    }

    public static void printDetails()
            // printDetails() method will display Report
    {
        System.out.println("DELIVERY REPORT - " + "created on " + Timestamp);
        System.out.println("*************************************************");
        System.out.println("TOWN: " + tChoice);
        System.out.println("WEIGHT:" + wChoice);
        System.out.println("PRICE:" + " $`enter code here`" + price);
        System.out.println("VAT (14%):" + vat);
        System.out.println("TOTAL DUE:" + total);
        System.out.println("COURIER:" + cChoice);
        System.out.println("*************************************************");
    }

    private static void time() 
    {
     Timestamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd      HH:mm:ss").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());

    }

    private static void townChoices() {
        String[] town = new String[3];
        town[0] = "CAPE TOWN";
        town[1] = "PRETORIA";
        town[2] = "DURBAN";

        Object selectedTown = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Choose town for parcel to be delivered to:", "Town options", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,null,town, "CAPE TOWN");
        tChoice = selectedTown.toString();
    }

    private static void weightChoices() 
    {
        String[] weight = new String[3];
        weight[0] = "0kg - 4kg";
        weight[1] = "5kg - 9kg";
        weight[2] = "Over 10kg";

        Object selectedTown = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Select the weight category of the parcel to be delivered to:"+ tChoice, "Town options", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,null,weight, "CAPE TOWN");
        wChoice = selectedTown.toString();

        price = Integer.parseInt(wChoice);
        if(wChoice.equals(weight[0]))
        {
            price = 300;
        }
        if(wChoice.equals(weight[1]))
        {
            price = 500;
        }
        if(wChoice.equals(weight[2]))
        {
            price = 700;
        }            
    }

    private static void courierChoices()
    {
        String[] courier = new String[3];
        courier[0] = "ABC Couriers";
        courier[1] = "Fast Track";
        courier[2] = "Rest Assured";

        Object selectedTown = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Select the courier company to deliver the parcel of weight" + wChoice + "to" + tChoice, "Town options", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,null,courier, "CAPE TOWN");
        cChoice = selectedTown.toString();
    }

    public static void vatAndtoal()
    {
        vat = price * 14/100;
        total = price + vat;
    }
}
```

Here is the exception that i receive:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "0kg - 4kg"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
    at delivery_details.Delivery_Details.weightChoices(Delivery_Details.java:77)
    at delivery_details.Delivery_Details.main(Delivery_Details.java:31)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). From that second link: "Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it." - so what is *your* difficulty in particular?

Comment: How is this code’s output failing to meet your expectations?

Comment: @VGR the code stops at the point after selecting the weight and then crashes. So getting the "price" for the selected weight category is the problem.

Comment: Be more specific than “crashes.”  If you’re referring to an exception, it is critical that you edit your question (using the “edit” link right below the shaded keyword rectangles at the end of your question), and add the *full stack trace* of that exception to your question.  That stack trace tells us, and you, what went wrong, where, and why.

Comment: The error is pretty self-explanatory:  `"0kg - 4kg"` does not represent an int value, obviously.  Since you’re setting `price` in the `if` statements that immediately follow, you should just remove that line of code entirely.  No need to assign `price` twice.

Comment: Thanks so much @VGR. Got it!